# RewriteRule to accept 2 parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
mydomain.com/MyFolder/parameter-1
```

I have this htaccess RewriteRule -

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [NC,L]
```

The .htaccess file is inside `MyFolder` and this only accept a single parameter.

How can do a RewriteRule to accept 2 parameters

```
mydomain.com/MyFolder/parameter-1/parameter-2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# mydomain.com/MyFolder/parameter-1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [NC,L]

# mydomain.com/MyFolder/parameter-1/parameter-2
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&d=$2 [NC,L]
```